# Writing blu-ray disc under linux with UDF only

Tags: linux, burning, blu-ray, udf

As I had said in the top, I cannot find it in k3b or other such options it seems to be iso9660 along with UDF instead of pure UDF as is required by the BD spec. So I need to know the best program to use to force the writing of the files as a pure UDF volume.

Comment: did you check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107883/creating-udf-image-in-linux

Comment: also can't you just create a writeable UDF partition and save it as an image after copying files to it? Then just burn image.

Comment: I found this guide too: https://thelinuxexperiment.com/create-a-virtual-hard-drive-volume-within-a-file-in-linux/

Comment: I was talking abuot writing the UDF disc that is fully UDF 2.5 which none of those do.

Comment: I see. I think imgburn can do that, but that's probably not available for linux.